# How to add functionality to MFC application

Tags: c++, mfc, ftdi

I have a sample code I'm using to watch for USB events using the FTDI D2XX library.  The sample is C++ code, and uses MFC which I've never touched before.  I'm trying to get this executable where I can make it into a .dll (which is a whole other can of worms), but without it having a main function because of MFC, I'm not sure how I can add functionality to this existing sample code (I just need to add one function).  This is the most complex project I've dealt with, and it's new to me so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Example 7 here:
http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/CodeExamples/VC.htm

Comment: It would be more helpful if we could see your sample.

Comment: Where do you want to call the one new function from? You could make it a new member of the dialog class, or just make a nonmember function if you want to call it from the thread.

Comment: I want to call it from inside the function that receives the USB events, so that every time the C code is called due to an event, the Java code gets called too.